# Cocos2d js dynamic light

Tags: dynamic, cocos2d-x-3.0, light, cocos2d-js, cocos2d-html5

Is there any way to use dynamic light in `cocos2d js` like this. I don't find any information about this, all links go only to cocos2d-x

[Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMWQSQQQMCk)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool by Codeandweb for creating cocos2d-js illuminations. I'm sure they describe how to use there output files. Though I didn't try yet.

https://www.codeandweb.com/spriteilluminator